# Populating a Databound ListView in ASP.NET/VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

I've searched on this for quite a while and haven't come up with anything, so the time has come to seek the help of SO.

I have a search function that will simultaneously search two tables for a value, only displaying the most up-to-date records. One of these tables will come from a set of four tables that is chosen by a drop-down list the user must select from. All four of these tables have different column names for similar data, so I have to decide what to put inside the Eval() based on that drop-down selection.

Here is the code for populating one cell inside of the ListView:

```
<%# If(CheckOverrides(Eval("MemUniqID"), "txtFirstName") <> Nothing,
       CheckOverrides(Eval("MemUniqID"), "txtFirstName"),
       Eval(FindDBField("txtFirstName"))
    )
 %>
```

Basically, I have to pass the unique identifier and another parameter to a function to find the most up-to-date record (housed in an override table). If the function returns nothing, then the original data (housed in one of the four tables) will display. The table's correct column name is returned from the FindDBField function.

The problem with this is if there are too many results in the search, the database connection just quits and closes itself. I've been trying to work out a better way to go about this that will cut down on the calls to the database (every call to CheckOverrides() and FindDBFields() will query the db once and I have about 8 fields I'm pulling into the ListView on each row, so that's 16 queries on each row returned), but I can't seem to work the code around properly.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Can't you create an ADODB.recordset to house your data and then search it without having to query the database that many times?

Comment: What database technology are you using? If the problem is the column names you can create Views or  Stored procedures with Column Aliases, and then just use the same column names from your .net code.

Comment: Is there a way to do that from code-behind to the aspx? I have switched the search results to store in a DataTable, but I haven't found a good way to use that for the ListView outside of binding it.

DB tables are in MySQL. I do have views set up for each table, but I didn't think to standardize the column names across the board. That's a great suggestion and I'm going to look into that. Can't see why I didn't think of doing that before :-P

Comment: Hopefully you can solve it with it. I feel your pain!

Comment: That will end up decreasing my code by at least a few hundred lines too... Thank you!